# How to Publish/Deploy Google Sheet script as API executable programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-api

I have a google sheet containing script, I want to perform following operations programmatically.

1. Make this Google spreadsheet `public` programmatically.
2. I want to execute the script associated with the above spreadsheet programmatically for any user (public).

Can I perform  "`Publish>Deploy as API executable`" programmatically?

Comment: Welcome to stack. Please include the code you have tried and describe any problems you are having with it.   Also please clean up your tags I don't think you are doing this in app script and .net.

Comment: @DaImTo, have you read my question carefully? Had there been a code to deploy google spreadsheet programmatically, would I bother to post a question?If you cant offer assistance, try to stay out of it.

Comment: I have done this before and can't help you fix your code without seeing it

Comment: @DaImTo can you refer me to some link, where I can find the solution of this problem, I don't have the code, refer me to some API link or any link on the web. I want to achieve this programmatically using API.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check the recent [updates in Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#october_2017) and see if it will help. It's stated:

> - You can now [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments) a script project directly from the project manifest.
> - We've updated the Publish script editor menu item to more accurately represent the various kinds of deployments a project can have, such as add-on, web app, or API executable deployments.

For more information, you may want to check these references:

- [Using the Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api)
- [Publishing an Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish)

Then, for features not currently supported, you may check or file a feature request [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features).

Comment: the above-given links do not provide any information to publish google spreadsheet using API, these are the only ways to deploy/publish manually using interface