# Google Apps Script: How are edit events from a bounded script in one sheet treated on another?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'll try to be as specific as possible. This questions relates to Google Apps Script, bounded to two sheets.

I have a function that runs on edit through an installable (not simple) trigger. (Installable because it needs to call e.g. GmailApp). Call it Sheet A.

On another sheet, which we'll call Sheet B, is a script which causes an edit to be made in a cell on Sheet A.

When an edit is made manually on Sheet A, the installable on-edit script runs fine.

When the edit is made via the script on Sheet B, the installable on-edit script does not run. In other words, there doesn't seem to be any event associated with edits made by a script.

I am wondering if there is any way to trigger the on-edit script on Sheet A to run when changes are being made through another, external, bounded script.

I've looked through GAS documentation and searched as best I can here, but I cannot find an answer. I've tried to use a simple trigger, but it also does not seem to "pick up" the edit event when performed by another script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers only run on "human" changes. You need to rethink your flow.

If you have a function `funA()` changing something programmatically in a cell and you need to trigger another function `funB()`, just call `funB()` directly from `funA()` without counting on a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

onEdit is triggered only if user updates a cell, not when the cell is updated programmatically.

You should expose onEdit from sheet A (or extract the method that actually does send the emails) and [publish it as API executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976233/how-to-publish-deploy-google-sheet-script-as-api-executable-programmatically)

Then you can call that method from sheet B, after the edit is made programmatically.